# How to change storage class of all objects in a folder of S3 bucket using boto3 via Lifecycle Configuration?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Can anyone share snippet for changing storage class of all objects in a Folder of S3 bucket using boto3.

Answer (score 5):

As described in the [S3 Storage Class documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-class-intro.html#sc-howtoset) you can define the storage class at the time you PUT the object on S3 or by making a COPY of an existing object.

Storage class is defined in the `x-amz-storage-class` HTTP header of the API call.

Using Boto3, you can specify the storage class at object creation time with the following code :

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
object = s3.Object('bucket_name','key')

object.put(StorageClass='STANDARD')
# accepted values are 'STANDARD' |'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY'|'STANDARD_IA'|'ONEZONE_IA'|'INTELLIGENT_TIERING'|'GLACIER'
```

Using Boto3, you can change the storage class by copying the following code :

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
object = s3.Object('new_bucket_name','newkey')
object.copy_from(CopySource = { Bucket: 'old_bucket_name', 'Key': 'old_key'}, StorageClass='STANDARD')
```

See [`put()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.put) for new objects and [`copy_from()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.copy_from) to copy an object and changing its storage class.

Comment: The equivalent via the AWS CLI is: `aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/ s3://my-bucket/ --recursive --storage-class ONEZONE_IA` (substituted desired storage class). This "copies" the object back onto itself, with the different storage class.